# REST Api interface di not working. Class ItemInterface does not exist

Tags: api, di, interface

ItemInterface:

```
namespace MyVendor\SampleModule1\Api\Data;

interface ItemInterface
{
    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName();

    /**
     * @return string|null
     */
    public function getDescription();
}
```

ItemRepositoryInterface:

```
<?php

namespace MyVendor\SampleModule1\Api;

use MyVendor\SampleModule1\Api\Data\ItemInterface;

interface ItemRepositoryInterface
{
    /**
     * @return ItemInterface[]
     */
    public function getList();
}
```

ItemRepository:

```
<?php

namespace MyVendor\SampleModule1\Model;

use MyVendor\SampleModule1\Api\ItemRepositoryInterface;
use MyVendor\SampleModule1\Model\ResourceModel\Item\CollectionFactory;

class ItemRepository implements ItemRepositoryInterface
{
    private $collectionFactory;

    public function __construct(CollectionFactory $collectionFactоry)
    {
        $this->collectionFactory = $collectionFactоry;
    }

    public function getList()
    {
        return $this->collectionFactory->create()->getItems();
    }
}
```

etc/di.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Framework\Console\CommandList">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="commands" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="myvendorAddItem" xsi:type="object">MyVendor\SampleModule1\Console\Command\AddItem</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
    <preference for="MyVendor\SampleModule1\Api\Data\ItemInterface" type="MyVendor\SampleModule1\Model\Item"/>
    <preference for="MyVendor\SampleModule1\Api\ItemRepositoryInterface" type="MyVendor\SampleModule1\Model\ItemRepository"/>
</config>
```

etc/webapi.xml

```
<routes xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Webapi:etc/webapi.xsd">
    <route url="/V1/myvendor" method="GET">
        <service class="MyVendor\SampleModule1\Api\ItemRepositoryInterface" method="getList" />
        <resources>
            <resource ref="anonymous" />
        </resources>
    </route>
</routes>
```

I ran the commands:

```
magento cache:flush
magento cache:clean
magento setup:di:compile
magento setup:upgrade
```

When i access the url http://mymage.com/rest/V1/myvendor i get the fallowing error:

```
<message>Class ItemInterface does not exist</message>
<code>-1</code>
<trace>
#0 /var/www/html/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Reflection/MethodsMap.php(149): ReflectionClass->__construct('ItemInterface') #1....
```

**EDIT:**

Item.php model:

```
<?php

namespace MyVendor\SampleModule1\Model;

use Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel;

class Item extends AbstractModel
{
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init(\MyVendor\SampleModule1\Model\ResourceModel\Item::class);
    }
}
```

I just don't understand where is the problem ? ? ?

Comment: where is your MyVendor\SampleModule1\Model\Item.php file?

Comment: i will edit  the questions 1 sec

Answer (score 1):

So, basically the ItemRepositoryInterface should look like:

```
<?php

namespace MyVendor\SampleModule1\Api;

interface ItemRepositoryInterface
{
    /**
     * @return \MyVendor\SampleModule1\Api\Data\ItemInterface[]
     */
    public function getList();
}
```

... I have no words .

Answer (score 1):

ItemRepositoryInterface:

The error message **Class ItemInterface does not exist**, provide the the namespace of ItemInterface in the Doc Block section.

In the ItemRepositoryInterface Doc Block is very very important and it should be

/** * @return \MyVendor\SampleModule1\Api\Data\ItemInterface[] */

See complete code below...

```
namespace MyVendor\SampleModule1\Api;

use MyVendor\SampleModule1\Api\Data\ItemInterface;

interface ItemRepositoryInterface
{
    /**
     * @return \MyVendor\SampleModule1\Api\Data\ItemInterface[]
     */
    public function getList();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace item.php file with below content,

```
<?php

namespace MyVendor\SampleModule1\Model;

use Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel;

class Item extends AbstractModel
{
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init(\MyVendor\SampleModule1\Model\ResourceModel\Item::class);
    }

    /**
     * Get name
     *
     * @return string|null
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return parent::getData('name');   
    }

    /**
     * Set name
     *
     * @param string $name
     * @return ItemInterface
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        return $this->setData('name', $name);
    }

    /**
     * Get Description
     *
     * @return string|null
     */
    public function getDescription()
    {
        return parent::getData('description');   
    }

    /**
     * Set Description
     *
     * @param string $description
     * @return ItemInterface
     */
    public function setDescription($description)
    {
        return $this->setData('description', $description);
    }
}
```

Comment: same error... nothing is changed

Comment: have you remove var/generation folder?

Comment: doesnt cache:flush and setup:upgrade do that ?

Comment: isn't this a di problem, not Model/Method structure one